# Different fonts for each language using storyboards in iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I'm facing a problem, where I need to use different fonts for each language that my application supports.
For example: I need to use "Arial" for Georgian language and "Times new roman" for English language.
Well, obviously there are lot's of ways solving this problem programmatically, but how this could be done using storyboards?

I have a UILabel on the view controller which is loaded from Storyboard. If I choose "Georgian" language in my iPhone settings >> General >> Language & Region >> PREFERRED LANGUAGE ORDER and open the application, the font of the label should be "Arial", but if I choose "English" language in iPhone settings, label's font should be "Times new roman".

**NOTE: There shouldn't be any storyboard outlets to the code for the label.**

The only thing doing this that comes to my head is to implement @IBInspectable property as UILabel extension and write some part of the code in it:

```
extension UILabel {
    @IBInspectable var adjustFont: Bool {
        get { return false } // we don't care about return value
        set { // this is where the game starts
            if newValue {
                switch systemLanguage {
                case .Georgian:
                    self.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 17)
                case .English:
                    self.font = UIFont(name: "Times new roman", size: 17)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Well, this is kinda solution but I'm looking more elegant/correct way doing this.

Any help/suggestions would be helpful.
Thank you

Comment: Hello, did you find any other solution for this that you can share ?

Comment: I think, unfortunately, there is no other way to achieve this, through the storyboard/xib, without IBInspectable property.
Or implement some part of the code, that will do it (Design system would be the most elegant way I guess)

Answer (score 0):

The way I do that is by creating a BaseLabel class as follows ... for ar and en ...

```
import UIKit

class BaseLabel: UILabel {
    @IBInspectable var arabicText:String = "" {
        didSet{
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var englishText:String = "" {
        didSet{
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var changeAlignment : Bool = true {
        didSet{
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        if arabicText != "" || englishText != "" {
            self.text = getCurrentLanguge() == .ar ? arabicText : englishText
        }
        if self.changeAlignment && textAlignment != .center{
            self.textAlignment = getCurrentLanguge() == .ar ? .right : .left
        }
        setFont()
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var fontSize: CGFloat = 13 {
        didSet {
            setFont()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var fontType: Int = 2 {
        didSet {
            setFont()
        }
    }
    
    func setFont() {
        if fontType == 1 {
            if getCurrentLanguge() == .en {
                self.font = UIFont(name: AppFonts.regularEn, size: UIDevice.isRunningOnIpad ? self.fontSize + 10.0 : self.fontSize)!
            } else {
                self.font = UIFont(name: AppFonts.regularAr, size: UIDevice.isRunningOnIpad ? self.fontSize + 10.0 : self.fontSize)!
            }
        }
        if fontType == 2 {
            if getCurrentLanguge() == .en {
                self.font = UIFont(name: AppFonts.boldEn, size: UIDevice.isRunningOnIpad ? self.fontSize + 10.0 : self.fontSize)!
            } else {
                self.font = UIFont(name: AppFonts.boldAr, size: UIDevice.isRunningOnIpad ? self.fontSize + 10.0 : self.fontSize)!
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

where AppFonts is a struct look like following...

```
struct AppFonts {
    
    static let fontSizeIPadButton = 24.0
    static let fontSizeButton = 17.0
    
    static let regularEn = "MyEnglishFontName-Regular"
    static let boldEn = "MyEnglishFontName-Bold"

    static let regularAr =  "MyArabicFontName-Regular"
    static let boldAr = "MyArabicFontName-Bold"
    
}
```

and UIDevice is an extension to make difference for ipad ...

```
extension UIDevice {
    static let isRunningOnIpad = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? true : false
}
```

when you assign the `BaseLabel` class to the label in the storyboard now u can control the fonts from storyboard...

[image]